Segmentation Fault Exception when running CPP code in VSC - SOLVED
I keep running into this segmentation fault when trying to run cpp code in Visual Studio Code.
My project includes two cpp files and one header.
I am not sure what to do with this issue.
The only extensions I have installed are these:
extensions
I have tried looking into the path variables and trying to see if moving my MSYS variable path higher than the iverilog path that is being loaded. Even after that, I still run into the same error.
I am not sure what to do next. Does anyone have any suggestions?
This issue seems to just be with VSC. I was able to get the program running when using Visual Studio.
[SOLVED] Sorry you guys, it ended up being a super simple fix. After doing all of those steps to fix the issue, I forgot to adjust my tasks.json to compile all of the cpp files instead of one. I also had removed the Code Runner extension which was previously installed, because it is apparently impossible for it to run multiple cpp files.
